# How to match string values of datetime format in both Jquery and PHP?

Tags: php, jquery

For example - 
In Jquery using the function (new Date()).getTime() am getting current datetime as 1470291303352.
But In PHP using strtotime(date('H:i:s')) am getting it as 1470291299.

Here i need to get the same string values. How to do it?

Comment: @madalinivascu Updated.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, php returns the number of seconds since 1970/01/01, jquery returns a number of milliseconds, so there is no way to be the same value.

Second - even if you've got the fastest server in the world it comes to the milliseconds in the execution of lines of code. So exactly the same value can hardly be achieved :)

What you can do to try to trim jquery for the last three numbers representing the milliseconds (this of course if you do these two lines of code to execute in one second :))

And for last, there is a issue of clocks on your server and client computer - it must be exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

The javascript method `getTime()` returns microseconds (http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_gettime.asp) whereas PHP `time()` (or in your case `strtotime()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) returns seconds. The first depends on your clients clock, the latter on your servers clock...

Mostly you never will get the same timestamps this way... maybe you could work around using some kind of AJAX api to have the same timestamp on both sides...

Answer (score 0):

Check this :

```
In php:
echo strtotime(date('H:i:s')); // 1470294647

In Script :
var date = new Date();
var d = Date.parse("'"+date+"'")/1000;   // 1470294647
alert(d);
```